# Standard Values value correct in CE but null in Code

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore8.2

If I set the value of a field on the standard values of a base template the standard value shows up in that field in the content editor(and in Rocks), however when I reference that field by ID in code

```
Html.Sitecore().Field(ID, Item);
```

//ED. I have a helper method that does error checking called GetField(), my mistake.
To add more clarity: this works correctly if I go into the CE and say add a character to the end of the value and press save. (overriding the standard values)

The returned value is null.

This both for new items created after the Standard Values change, and current items.

Comment: Just came across this issue as well right now, going to dig deeper, but I think this might be a Sitecore bug. Can you tell me the version of Sitecore in which you encountered this error?

Answer (score 0):

Try: **.Field()** instead of **.GetField()**

Like in Html.Sitecore().Field(ID, Item);

Comment: I am actually using Field, typed the name of a helper field that checks for null.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is answered here, even though it seems like a Sitecore bug regarding item fallback and fields that inherit their value from standard values:
[Language Fallback not working for Fields with Standard Values (Sitecore 8.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39585520/language-fallback-not-working-for-fields-with-standard-values-sitecore-8-1)

The reason I'm saying that there is the solution is because I was able to solve it just that way before I even read that answer. Simply put, it seems like Sitecore does not pull standard values for fields in case of item fallback, as if I disabled item fallback the fields with standard values were not null anymore in code : (

But a probably better solution is field level fallback: if you enable field level fallback on that exact field in the template, it will pull in the standard values as well when an item fallback happens.